# wpf application with multilingual support

Tags: wpf, multilingual

Simple form with some information. One drop down to select language  like below:

```
 <controls:LanguageControl Width="155" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,5"  SelectedCultureInfo="{Binding CurrentLanguage,Mode=TwoWay}"></controls:LanguageControl>

 private CultureInfo _lang;
    public CultureInfo CurrentLanguage
    {
        set
        {
            _lang = value;
            if (!System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Equals(_lang))
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = _lang;
                AppSettings.SetValue(SettingsKeys.LANGUAGE, _lang.LCID);
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = value;
                WPFCommon.Localization.LocalizeDictionary.Instance.Culture = value;
                Rhino.Main.Properties.Resources.Culture = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentLanguage");
            }
        }
        get 
        {
            if (_lang == null)
            {
                _lang = new CultureInfo(Convert.ToInt32(AppSettings.GetValue(SettingsKeys.LANGUAGE)));
            }
            return _lang;
        }
    }
```

When I restart application, all text is replaced by selected language.
But how would I do right away without restarting application?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the problem here, but I'd highly recommend using [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2007/10/30/wpf-localization-on-the-fly-language-selection.aspx) infrastructure. It's based on `Binding` so the updates are taken care of.

Comment: my problem is, i want to change application Lagrange immediately when user change language.   right now it works after user restart application

Comment: I understand this, but it seems that changing culture of the thread is not triggering UI update of strings and such. Can you post here a sample of how you get the localized values? Maybe some `TextBlock` with definition of its Text property?